# Solution of an integral with the interval 1, x^4

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to find
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_1^{x^4} \sec t\ dt.$$

How would one go about resolving this integral? I am having problems after I substitute $x^4$ with $u.$

Comment: Fundamental theorem of calculus: $$\frac{d}{dx} \int_a^x f(t) dt = f(x).$$ Now just use chain rule,  you don't have to find the integral of $\sec t$. What is your problem after substituting $u = x^4$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \int_{a}^{x}f(t) \mathrm{dt} = f(x)$$

Notice that the bound involves $x$ rather than a function of $x$. When you have a function of $x$ instead, simply use the Chain Rule:

$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm du} \cdot \frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dx}$$

Combining both gives

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \int_{a}^{u}f(t) \mathrm{dt} = \left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm du} \int_{a}^{u}f(t) \mathrm{dt}\right) \cdot \frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dx} = f(u) \cdot u'$$

Here, $u = x^4$, so $u' = 4x^3$, and $f(u)$ simply becomes $\sec(u) = \sec\left(x^4\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x) = \int_0^x \sec(t) \,\mathrm{d}t$.  Then you want $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} g(x^4)$, which you should be able to do by the chain rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus (which tells you want $g'(x)$ is).

Answer (score 0):

It is the derivative of a composite function.

You have one function 
 $$g(x)=x^4$$ and another function $$ F(x) = \int _0 ^ x \sec t dt $$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{x^4} \sec t\, dt =  4x^3 \sec (x^4)$$

Can you figure it out using the fundamental theroem of calculus?

Answer (score 0):

Use chain rule and Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Differentiate the integral first then the upper bound of the integral. (i.e)

$$\int_1^{x^4} \sec (t) dt$$

When you take its derivative, this becomes

$$4x^3 \sec (x^4)$$

This happened by both Chain Rule and FTC - Part I